# Регулярное выражение на составную строку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java, c#

Предположим есть строка, которая не начинается одной строкой (иван) и заканчивается другой строкой (марья). Например,

> петр марья - подходит
> иван марья - не подходит
> иван дарья - не подходит

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Например, используя [negative lookahead](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444):

```
^(?!иван).*?марья$
```